# Determine what SQL Server version am I currently using on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with this, I have multiple SQL Server version, and I wanted to delete the others so that I can have only one version, but I can't determine what my visual studio is currently using and I don't know what should be deleted so that I can get rid of the whole SQL Server version. Hope you can help me thanks.

[image: I have attached a screenshot of my SQL Server versions]

[image]

Comment: What's in your Visual Studio connection strings? You could be using all of them. It's probably easier to go into services and stop them one by one to see what breaks

Comment: That is a lot of SQL Servers - 2012, 2014, and some 2016.  One approach would be to keep the version you want to use and remove the others.  In apps you're building in Visual Studio, you'd then just target the SQL Server you left on the system.  It would be nice to know if one of these SQL Servers was running as the default instance.  The "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition" can be left if you have or think you will have a need to do Compact Edition development.

Comment: @STLDeveloper I have added photo on the question, how will I know what should I delete on the second photo? thanks for your consideration

Comment: @Newbie10 - regardless of which SQL Server instances you remove, none of the items listed in that second image need to be removed.

Comment: @STLDeveloper thanks for your advice, it helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you open a connection to the database within Visual Studio you can run the statement `SELECT @@Version` which will tell you more information.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177512.aspx

For example when I run it I get

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)     Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Developer Edition (64-bit) on
>   Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

as the result.

Comment: So for example if I have 2014 as version, should I delete all the components not having 2014? like the 2016 version?

Comment: It depends on whether you will need them. If you know that you won't need them then it should be safe to delete but if you have (for example) legacy applications that work with older version of SQL then they can be handy to have around.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can configure the default instancein Tools - Options - Database Tools. You can also use Sql Configuration Manager to see the names of instances to help you identify them.

Answer (score 0):

With an open connection, you can run the following statement:

```
select serverproperty('ProductVersion')
```

That will give you a string that is programmatically parsable, like `'9.00.5000.00'` for an old Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or `'12.0.2000.8'` for Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx